# Summable interface

Tags: java

I'm currently learning Java on CodeHS (Java - Latte). I encountered this example about interface but not really understand the method. Why does the `public int add(Summable other)` need to the define the type of other as Summable? Isn't Summable is an interface and not an object?

I tested by deleting the Summable in `public int add(Summable other)` and the program couldn't run. Thank you!

This is the interface:

```
public interface Summable()
{
  public int add(Summable other);
  public int getValue();
}
```

Here is the example from the program:

```
public class Book implements Summable()
{
  private int numPages;
  private String title;
  
  public Book (String title, int numPages)
  {
     this.title = title;
     this.numPages = numPages;
  }

  public int add(Summable other)
  {
     return getValue() + other.getValue();
  }

  public int getValue()
  {
     return this.numPages;
  }
 }
```

Comment: `Summable other` means that `other` needs to be something that implements `Summable`.

Comment: This is frankly a bizarre use for interfaces. I had to stare at it for a bit to figure out what it's trying to do. That's not your fault, of course (it's the tutorial's fault), but do take some things with a grain of salt. An interface which defines `getValue` could be reasonable, but then `add` should be a static method, since it will never meaningfully be overridden to do different things. Having it be an interface method is strange.